# Getting Imported address privet keys. (Blockchain)

Tags: blockchain.info

Am trying to get the private key for an imported address but am unable to do so.
I did tried to use the blockchain method but still unsucessful as I don't have the  private key on the tab.
[image: No privet key tab]

Comment: Not clear on the intention ... you cannot simply import a public key, and then automagically have the priv keys. This would allow to steal all funds. I assume you have a different use case behind?

Answer (score 1):

Only if you have inserted the private key, you will be able to export the private key again. So in your case, you never gave blockchain your private key. So you are unable to export it. Blockchain cannot magically create the private key.